# The fields (of scienrific expertise) required by crew members in order to conduct research on an unknown planet

Tags: science-based, technology, planets, spaceships, alternate-earth

I am working on a story where a group of people in the supposed future leave their planet in a spaceship to do research on another not yet known planet (more or less like Prometheus).

Let there be four (4) crew members.
Let spaceship be automated or autopilot except during emergencies.
Let the planet be an abandoned world with evidence of alien life and high tech infrastructures.

1. It would be helpful if someone could explain what are the important fields of expertise the crew members would need for a research mission to the planet.
2. Do those fields have to be shared by all crew members?
   If yes, would this be possible for normal people similar to us to have multiple areas of expertise?
3. How should they commence their research mission?

Links, articles and books regarding my question is preferable so as to make the answer easy. Suggestions regarding the story building will be useful.

***THANKS FOR YOUR VALUABLE ANSWERS***

Comment: Hello Peaceman, I believe this question is a duplicate. Did you search on this site?

Answer (score 1):

Well they should have

Earth sciences

- anthropology: the study of human societies and cultures and their development.
- archaeology: the study of human history and prehistory through the excavation of sites and the analysis of artifacts and other physical remains.
- geology: the science that deals with the earth's physical structure and substance, its history, and the processes that act on it.

Life sciences

- biology: defined as the scientific study of life, is an incredibly broad and diverse field
- exobiology: the branch of science that deals with the possibility and likely nature of life on other planets or in space
- medicine: the science or practice of the diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of disease

Computer sciences

- cryptography: the art of writing or solving codes.
- linguistics: the scientific study of language and its structure, including the study of morphology, syntax, phonetics, and semantics.
- computer science: the study of the principles and use of computers.
- machine AI - the study of advanced Artificial intelligence and machine learning

And then one left for the lead project manager, who should probably have some military training or belong to a branch of the military.

I can go into more detail on why I think these are a minimum set of skills they would need

For #2 - it never hurts to cross train as it were, but as you are limited to 4 crew and the fields they must know are already pretty broad I think that will be hard, unless they have some better learning techniques in the future.  Basically it depends how long it takes them to become an expert in each field they need and other fields.